# WSImport comments out my @EJB annotation

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, ejb, wsimport

I have a JAX-WS web service generated from WSDL via wsimport. In a class implementing `@javax.jws.WebService` I have an instance variable which is an EJB. So this EJB instance variable is annotated with `@EJB`. Every time I regenerate web service using `wsimport` this annotation gets commented out. The rest of code remains untouched. Why is that?

Comment: What is EJB version you are working on ?

Comment: @KalpaGunarathna I think it doesn't matter, because EJB libraries / runtime are not involved here, but it seems that it is 3.1. What is your idea of what could be wrong? I added new operation in my WSDL. WSImport analyze Java classes, when WSDL operation exists in Java code it does nothing. If WSDL operation does not exists in Java code it is added there. But I don't know why annotation on instance variable gets commented out.

Comment: I was thinking some incompatiable version clash between EJB version and wsimport by JDK.  If EJB version is 3.1 it means its final release was back in 2009. So it might be incompatible with wsimport in JDK 8 or 7. This might not be the case. But might be a good suggestion to recheck the versions :)